# sql запрос вывести значение первым если равно

Tags: mysql

Товарищи ломаю голову как сделать финт ушами!=) Буду признателен за помощь, или за информацию, что такое провернуть не удастся! MySQL.

В общем такой запрос сейчас

```
SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`  FROM `users` where `group` = '1'
```

Что хочется получить в итоге- что-то наподобия такого

```
SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`  FROM `users` where `group` = '1'
IF `id` = `какое то число`, то вывести его первым в списке потом все остальное.
```

Вот если честно фантазии не хватает, а прогуглить тему не хватает времени, зашиваюсь с работой... Буду очень признателен, за помощь.

Поймите и простите!=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`  
FROM `users` 
where `group` = '1' 
ORDER BY case when id=<какое-то число> then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Выручили! Работает=) У меня к Вам просьба, если не сложно, вкратце объясните что такое case и then 0 else 1 end. Хочу на будущее знать эти моменты. Then (тогда) 0 else (иначе) 1 ? не совсем очевидно как оно работает... Заранее спасибо и спасибо еще раз за помощь!

Comment: Упорядочить по выражению "если id=<какое-то число> тогда 0 иначе 1"

Comment: В общем случае конструкция case when x then y when x1 then y1 when x2 then y2 else z en - это получение результата в различных условиях. Какое первое выполнилось - тот результат и получили, если не выполнилось ни одно условие из when - то возвращается результат, указанный в else. http://sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page1.html

Comment: @Константин case это боле менее универсальное средство, совместимое с многими SQL. если условие выполняется то возвращается значение then иначе из else. order by соотв. ставит в начале записи с 0, потом с 1. Конкретно для MySQL то же самое можно написать короче `if(id=NNN,0,1)`

Comment: @Mike Спасибо большое! Объяснили доходчиво и понятно!!! Вот с 0 и 1 кокраз не очевидно было, теперь буду знать! Вот такие ответы самые доходчивые и понятные! Спасибо!!!